# boot2docker changing IP address from default 192.168.59.103 to 192.168.59.104 (Mac)

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, osx-yosemite, boot2docker

boot2docker was running all the time on 192.168.59.**103**.

Suddenly the command `boot2docker ip` gives 192.168.59.**104**.

The problem is that now I have to change all my [`/etc/hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) entries.

**How can I make the boot2docker IP address static?**

Side question: Should I avoid boot2docker completely and run everything inside a [Vagrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagrant_(software)) machine?

I am running on [Mac OS X v10.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite).

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already done so, create a Docker configuration with:

```
boot2docker config > ~/.boot2docker/profile
```

Then edit your Docker configuration with the following line:

```
UpperIP = "192.168.59.103"
```

Then follow the other steps to clear out your old Docker images and start a new one.

I was also having issues connecting to Docker, but a system restart resolved them.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the virtual machine from the VirtualBox GUI (delete everything) it works again on 103. I guess something messed up with boot2docker while using it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the VM and restart it again like @ramden suggested you could do:

You can remove all containers from the current environment by running

`$ docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

To remove all images:

`$ docker rmi $(docker images -q)`

Restart the VM, cleaning all cache from old images, doing the following

```
$ boot2docker delete
$ boot2docker init
$ boot2docker start
```

I've just encountered the same issue and couldn't find an answer right away, maybe this is worth for future interest.

Cheers.